# overriding specific functions in meteor packages

Tags: meteor

I am trying to find a way to override specific functions in meteor packages.  The only way I have found to do it is to download the package and use it locally.  Is there a quick way that I could just override one function without doing this? (as one would expect to be able to do in most OOP languages)

Comment: what else have you tried that didn't work? Does the obvious (`MyPackage.myFunction = newFunction`) not work when placed, e.g., in `Meteor.startup`?